# How to specify bit depth and sample rate when recording microphone using mediaRecorder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, microphone, mediarecorder

In general, a standard CD's duration is 74 min, sample rate is 44.1KHZ, left and right two-channel (stereo). Its capacity can be calculated using the following formula:

`(44100*16*2)/8*(74*60)=783216000bytes`

Does 16 mean the bit depth?

Below is the code snippet that I use to do the recording.

```
const options = {
    mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=pcm',
    audioBitsPerSecond: 128
};
const recordedChunks = []
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options)
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function (e) {
    if (e.data.size > 0) {
        recordedChunks.push(e.data)
    }
})
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', function () {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(new Blob(recordedChunks))
})
mediaRecorder.start()
```

After searching the documentation, I didn't find the bit depth, channel and sample rate option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the sample rate, channel count, and bit depth by modifying a  **[MediaTrackConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints)** object, then applying it to a **MediaStreamTrack** using MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraint(*constraints*). The **MediaStreamTrack** should be accessible through the **MediaStream** going into your **MediaRecorder**.

(The 16 in your equation does refer to the bit-depth)

(**44100** samples * **16** bits per sample * **2** channels of audio) / **8** bits per byte * (**74** minutes * **60** seconds per minute) = **783216000** bytes

Comment: Does bit depth means sampleSize? I specify the params like this: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { sampleSize: 16, channelCount: 1, sampleRate: 16000 } }).then(stream => { var audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0]; console.log(audioTrack.getSettings()) })`, in chrome, the logged audio settings is `{ "deviceId": "default", "echoCancellation": false }`, it seems that the params isn't working, and the mozilla doc also indicates that the Audio track properties is not supported. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: hi, Any solution?

Comment: This answer does not work for me. From what I'm reading, the API does not guarantee that these constraints will have an effect.